# Content that flows from center to the sides (with CSS)

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm working on a layout that has two columns which need to be centered. Each column needs to grow to adapt its width depending on its children content.

The problem for me is that the columns needs to grow **from the center to the sides**, and all its children need to have the same height and width.

What I need:

[image: Desired layout]

As you can see the boxes are all the same height & width. I don't want to manually set those values, I'd like all the boxes to take the size of the longest text inside them (as in 2)

This layout wasn't designed for a website and now I'm kind of stuck trying to make it work like one. I've tried with flexbox reading [this](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but it seems it only works with fixed-width children.

I've tried having two columns with `display: inline-block` and 'text-align: center`: that makes the columns centered but doesn't solve the issue of its children width/height

I know it might be difficult to understand the question but I'd appreciate any ideas or orientation. I was thinking of plain CSS/SASS solution but will listen to javascript alternatives.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can't you just align the text to the right on the left box?

Comment: @Huangism but how would that make all the boxes the same width? now they are as wide as the text inside them so they have different widths. I'll make a fiddle and add it to the post.

Comment: Probably need to use js for this

Comment: What determines the width of the two columns? can you specify a min width for example?

Comment: How many rows will be in the layout? fixed? variable?

Answer (score 1):

I happened to be making something similar the other day. **I feel like this is a partial answer at best**; it solves the layout issue, but I think you would **need JavaScript** to increase the width of the columns dynamically as you describe. Perhaps someone else can combine this answer with some JS (I don't know JS well enough to answer) to achieve what you're seeking. Do note, however, that the widths here are percentages, so they **do** grow, in a sense, as you re-size the browser window.

Further, I find your question a little confusing in that you say you **don't** want to manually specify a height value, but you want the boxes to be the same height. The only way for this to happen is if you have the same amount of content in each box, otherwise your boxes will be different heights (or you **must** manually specify a height, absolute or relative).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G4VAc/17/)

**HTML** (with filler text):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf jkl; jkl; jkl; jkl; asdf</div><div class="right">jkl;<br/>asdf</div>
    <div class="left">asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf jkl; jkl; jkl; jkl; asdf</div><div class="right">jkl;<br/>asdf</div>
</div>
```

Notice there's no space between the left and right inner divs. If you add a space, then the div will move down to a new line.

**CSS**:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 12.5% auto;
    position: relative;
}

.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background: #aebab1;
}

.right {
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #e2dde1;
}
```

Comment: You make a very good point about the height of the content cell.  Consider the cell with the longest text line, what is the maximum width that the cell will take? half the page? If so, then that cells sets the height, but that depends on the content, and CSS cannot sample content, determine a height, and then set that height to the rest of the siblings.  JavaScript/jQuery can do that however.  Tables might be able to do this BUT you need to know the number of rows ahead of time, and the solution may not hold across all browsers.